# How to translate SQL to DAX and create calculated table in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I have a table with 3 columns: `EffectiveDate`, `ActualStatus`, `PredictedStatus`.

[image]

I need to Group By `EffectiveDate` and Count the number of each status for `ActualStatus` column and for `PredictedStatus` column.

In sql I'd do that like this:

```
 select EffectiveDate,
        ActualStatus,
        SUM(case when ActualStatus = 'Bound' then 1 
                 when ActualStatus = 'Declined' then 1
                 when ActualStatus = 'Quoted' then 1
                 when ActualStatus = 'Not Taken Up' then 1
                 when ActualStatus = 'Indication' then 1
                 when ActualStatus = 'Submitted' then 1
                 when ActualStatus = 'Lost' then 1
                 when ActualStatus = 'Indicated' then 1
        else 0 end) as CountActual,
        PredictedStatus,
        SUM(case when PredictedStatus = 'Bound' then 1
                 when PredictedStatus = 'Not Bound' then 1
                 ELSE NULL end) as CountPredicted

from #Test
group by 
        EffectiveDate,
        ActualStatus,
        PredictedStatus
```

The result should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow the same logic, create two calculated columns similar to your SQL case statement.

```
if [ActualStatus] = "Bound" or
   [ActualStatus] = "Declined" or
   [ActualStatus] = "Quoted" or
   [ActualStatus] = "Not Taken Up" or
   [ActualStatus] = "Indication" or
   [ActualStatus] = "Submitted" or
   [ActualStatus] = "Lost" or
   [ActualStatus] = "Indicated"
then 1
else 0
```

and

```
if [PredictedStatus] = "Bound" or
   [PredictedStatus] = "Not Bound"
then 1
else null
```

Then Group By your first three columns and sum over the other columns as seen below:

[image: GroupBy]

The resulting query will look something like this in your Advanced Editor:

```
let
    Test = <Insert Data Source Here>,
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Test, "CountActual", each if [ActualStatus] = "Bound" or [ActualStatus] = "Declined" or [ActualStatus] = "Quoted" or [ActualStatus] = "Not Taken Up" or [ActualStatus] = "Indication" or [ActualStatus] = "Submitted" or [ActualStatus] = "Lost" or [ActualStatus] = "Indicated" then 1 else 0),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "CountPredicted", each if [PredictedStatus] = "Bound" or [PredictedStatus] = "Not Bound" then 1 else null),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"Day", "ActualStatus", "PredictedStatus"}, {{"CountActual", each List.Sum([CountActual]), type number}, {"CountPredicted", each List.Sum([CountPredicted]), type number}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Day", "ActualStatus", "CountActual", "PredictedStatus", "CountPredicted"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```